# data posting to bluepay

Tags: php

I am implementing a bluepay payment gateway in my PHP project. I couldn't find any integration documents for bluepay, Plaese anyone tell me the basic steps for posting data to bluepay, ie in which format I have to use to post data to "https://bluepay.onlinedatacorp.com/test/bluepaylitetest.asp".

Comment: if you go to the site and login they will have documentation and possibly integrations for php, .Net, etc..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has [already been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513016/blue-pay-integration-in-php) and i don't think you should repeat without a proper google search (even a non-proper in this case).